# Could PDO::lastInsertId() be inaccurate?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've got a page calling a script via AJAX which could be asynchronously called multiple times simultaneously from the same parent page.  This script uses require_once to access a configuration script with the database handler.  Will the script call a unique instance of this handler each time, or if multiple copies are open will they all be using the same instance and causing undesirable results when I attempt to get the ID of the last insert from that instance of the script?

**Just to be clear, this is the command I'm referencing:**

```
$DBH->lastInsertId()
```

Thanks!

Comment: this site suggests answers for the trivial questions while you're typing it. Please pay attention to these suggestions

Comment: @YourCommonSense It wasn't offered to me.

Comment: Huh.  Sorry about that, I was confident I'd checked it as I am typically good about it.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) says

> This method may not return a meaningful or consistent result across different PDO drivers, because the underlying database may not even support the notion of auto-increment fields or sequences.

That being said, I've never had a problem using `lastInsertId` with MySQL.  It's always worked.

This ostensibly wraps a call to [MySQL's `LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client.

i.e. it should be safe to use even if you are facing frequent requests.

Comment: Reputation points are so sweet, aren't they?

Comment: @YourCommonSense you seem to lack a substantial amount of common sense in spite of your username

Comment: So then it's on a per-connection basis and, more relevantly, each instance of the script will be opening a unique connection.  Is that unquestioningly correct?  (I'm implementing something on an existing server and if this goes wrong my clients will be deleting each other's content, so I need to be extremely careful.)

Comment: @JS yes it is; each time you call `new PDO` for example.  I know exactly what you are trying to implement and I have used `lastInsertId` in these circumstances before with no problem.  If you like, you can easily test it.  Update your ajax script to `sleep` for some period of time and hit it twice quickly.  You should confirm you get the right IDs

Comment: I'll trust you as you seem rather knowledgeable.  I could have tested it of course, but if I'm going to rely on testing I'd want it to be rather more extensive than that and despite working with a rather sensitive/critical infrastructure here I'm also on a major time crunch.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: And I must ask, what exactly do you think I'm implementing?  I'm curious how close you are.

Comment: @JS Not something I'm working on now, but I have worked on it in the past.  I still suggest that you test just for your own peace of mind, but I'm quite confident in my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39023/discussion-between-explosion-pills-and-j-s)

Answer (score 2):

`$DBH->lastInsertId()` retrieves, in case of MySQL, the result of `last_insert_id()` function.

The `last_insert_id()` is session based, which means that if you have 2 PHP scripts running, you will only get the ones `last_insert_id` that were generated by each script.

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a
>   per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the
>   function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated
>   for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that
>   client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they
>   generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures
>   that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the
>   activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or
>   transactions.

[MySQL and PDO: Could PDO::lastInsertId theoretically fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931165/mysql-and-pdo-could-pdolastinsertid-theoretically-fail?rq=1)

Comment: So this is a yes.

Answer (score -1):

As noted in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php):

> Note: This method may not return a meaningful or consistent result
>   across different PDO drivers, because the underlying database may not
>   even support the notion of auto-increment fields or sequences.

Comment: I don't see how that's directly relevant to my question.