# How to get last inserted record from sql server using PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to insert data in sql server 2005 using PDO object in PHP.

Also I want to retrieve last inserted id which is auto generated.

any one help me.

Comment: [PDO::lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Answer (score 1):

In the session that the insert occured issue a

```
select scope_identity()
```

will return the last generated identity column inserted.

Comment: This isn't how it should be done. It can be done with one call to db. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: I don't know PHP so this being a SQL Server group I gave the SQL Server answer. It may not be appropriate in a PHP client program.

Comment: @chris85 I also don't know PHP but that seems to have a potential issue. What if there is a insert trigger on the table? Does it return the last identity value from the base table or the value from the trigger?

Comment: I just tried inserting on a table with a trigger. In the main session it returned the identity column value from the table not from the table that was inserted through the trigger.

Comment: Here's another thread on it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931165/mysql-and-pdo-could-pdolastinsertid-theoretically-fail. With the `scope_identity` I think you could get incorrect values. I'd need to see a full code sample to advise more though.

Comment: That conversation seems to be about Mysql. In SQL Server you will always get the last identity value automatically created in a given session.